# Comparing classes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made 3 boxes, and I want to show a different text for each of them when clicked.

HTML:

```
    <div class="box thursday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img src="assets/images/box.png">
    </div>
    <div class="box friday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img src="assets/images/box.png">
    </div>

    <div class="box saturday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img src="assets/images/box.png">
    </div>
```

And i have the texts:

```
        <div class="thursday display">
            <p>Para confirmar sua reserva aceite nosso aplicativo.</p>
        </div>
```

I have this others, but i'm testing only with the first box.

```
<!--         <div class="friday display">
                <p>Para confirmar sua reserva aceite nosso aplicativo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="saturday display">
                <p>Para confirmar sua reserva aceite nosso aplicativo.</p>
            </div>    -->
```

I made the same stylesheet for the 3:

```
.thursday,
.friday,
.saturday {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

And also I configured display none

```
.display {
    display: none;
}
```

Now I need the first text to appear only when the first box is clicked, and so consecutively

for this, I did this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this) == '.box.thursday-box') {
            $('.thursday').toggleClass('display');
        }
        else {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

So, only if the box i clicked have the class .box.thurday-box, the first text will appear. But it is returning the error, anyone why?

I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `data()` for this:

```
<div data-day="thursday" class="box thursday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">...</div>
<div data-day="friday" class="box friday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">...</div>
<div data-day="saturday" class="box saturday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">...</div>
```

Then:

```
var elmDay = $(this).data('day');
$('.' + elmDay).toggleClass('display');
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$(this)` refers to the element being clicked as a jQuery object - you actually have to get the class attribute ( `$(this).attr("class")` ). jQuery includes a `hasClass` method that would probably work nicer for you:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('thursday-box')) {
```

Comment: It would actually be `.hasClass('thursday-box')` (remove the dot...).

Comment: I will accept your answer in 15 min. Thanks @TrevanHetzel

Comment: Or `$(this).is('.thursday-box')` if you're doing code golf.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Html

```
 <div data-day="thursday" class="box thursday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img src="assets/images/box.png">
    </div>
    <div data-day="friday" class="box friday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img src="assets/images/box.png">
    </div>
    <div data-day="saturday" class="box saturday-box col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img src="assets/images/box.png">
    </div>
    <div class="weekday">
        <div data-day="thursday">
            <p><strong>Thursday</strong> Para confirmar sua reserva aceite nosso aplicativo.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-day="friday">
            <p><strong>Friday</strong> Para confirmar sua reserva aceite nosso aplicativo.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-day="saturday">
            <p><strong>Saturday</strong> Para confirmar sua reserva aceite nosso aplicativo.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css

```
.weekday > div {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Javascript / Jquery

```
$('.box').on('click', function(){
    $('.weekday > div').hide();
    $('.weekday > div[data-day="'+$(this).data('day')+'"').show();
})
```

See Example Here

http://jsfiddle.net/Papacidero/zqoLb1L9/1/